# Connection Time out with Error Text in Web.Config file

Tags: asp.net, mysql, web-config, connection-timeout

Hi I sometimes get the following error

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a
>   configuration file required to service this request. Please review the
>   specific error details below and modify your configuration file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 61:              applicationName="/" Line 62:
>   name="MySqlRoleProvider" Line 63:
>   type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider,
>   MySql.Web,Version=6.5.4.0,
>
>   Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" Line 64:  Line 65:
>   autogenerateschema="true" />
>
> Source File: E:\EDUCATIONAL\DOT
>   NET\website\WebSite1\WebSite1\web.config

the error at line 62 to 65 are in roleManager

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add connectionStringName="conStr"
             applicationName="/"
             name="MySqlRoleProvider"
             type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web,Version=6.5.4.0,&#xD;&#xA;             Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"

             autogenerateschema="true" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

How to avoid this problem and what actually is happening here?
I understand that it is a connection time out error but my page is not yet taken time to load. I got the error suddenly after I navigated to the required page with in fraction of seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be your connection string causing the issue and the RoleManager is unable to connect to your MySql database using your current connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You have a linebreak and spaces encoded into your connection string:

```
&#xD;&#xA;
```

That may very well be what is breaking.

Comment: That is what for I am breaking my head. Connection Time out with "Error Text" in Web.Config file. It says the error text &#xD;&#xA; is inserted some times with out my intervention, no matter howmany times I cleared it.

Comment: My point is that if you _are_ using source control, this error may have been checked in and you are getting it every time you updates from source control

Comment: @hungrycoder - Then you need to find out what is changing the file. It doesn't spontaneously change.